# Test Class Failing

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm having trouble getting my test class to pass tests.  Getting:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   UpdateAccountActivityDescription: execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
>   System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>   Trigger.UpdateAccountActivityDescription: line 6, column 1: []

as an error.

**Trigger**

```
trigger UpdateAccountActivityDescription on Task (after insert,after update) {
 if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
    // We need to update associated Opportunity Fields with Fields from Case.
    Account acc = [SELECT Id, Recent_Activity_Notes__c, Recent_Activity_Date__c, Recent_Activity_Owner__c From Account WHERE Id = :t.WhoId ];

    acc.Recent_Activity_Notes__c = t.Description;
    acc.Recent_Activity_Date__c = t.CreatedDate;
    acc.Recent_Activity_Owner__c = t.WhoId;


    update acc;
    }
    }
}
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class UpdateAccountActivityDecscription_Test {

    static testMethod void CreateAccountTask(){


        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert acc;
    }     

    static testMethod void CreateTask(){
        Account acc1 = new Account();
        acc1.Name = 'Test Account1';
        acc1.Recent_Activity_Notes__c = 'Test Version one';
        acc1.Recent_Activity_Date__c = date.parse('12/12/2013');
        insert acc1;

     Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];
        User u1 = new User(Alias = 'testa', Email ='test@testapple.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId= p.Id,
                          TimeZoneSidKey= 'America/Los_Angeles', UserName= 'test@testapple.com');

        System.runAs(u1) {

            Task t1 = New Task();
            t1.Subject = 'Task1 New';
            t1.Description = 'Update Task1 Name';
            t1.WhatId = acc1.id;
            insert t1;

            t1.Description = 'New New New Task1';
            update t1;

        }      
        }
}
```

Comment: Be careful as any task created against another type not related to an account will cause this to fail.

Answer (score 1):

This trigger should fix the problem and is also bulkified:

```
trigger UpdateAccountActivityDescription on Task (after insert, after update) {
    Map<Id, Task> m = new Map<Id, Task>();
    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if (t.AccountId != null) m.put(t.AccountId, t);
    }
    if (m.size() > 0) {
        Account[] accounts = new Account[] {};
        for (Id id : m.keySet()) {
            Task t = m.get(id);
            accounts.add(new Account(
                    Id = id,
                    Recent_Activity_Notes__c = t.Description;
                    Recent_Activity_Date__c = t.CreatedDate;
                    Recent_Activity_Owner__c = t.WhoId;
                    ));
        }
        update accounts;
    }
}
```

You do not need to check the `Trigger.isAfter` and `Trigger.isUpdate` as that filtering is already done because of the `after insert, after update` in the trigger signature. And update of the modified Accounts is needed because that is a different object than the trigger is operating on, but there is no need to query the Account you can just set the ID and update.

**PS**

You can add in logic related to the WhoId by making use of the [getSObjectType](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_Id_getSObjectType) and [newSObject](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm#apex_Schema_SObjectType_newSObject_2) methods to create the correct type:

```
trigger UpdateDescriptions on Task (after insert, after update) {
    Map<Id, Task> m = new Map<Id, Task>();
    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if (t.AccountId != null) m.put(t.AccountId, t);
        if (t.WhoId != null) m.put(t.WhoId, t)
    }
    if (m.size() > 0) {
        SObjects[] sobs = new SObject[] {};
        for (Id id : m.keySet()) {
            Task t = m.get(id);
            SObject sob = id.getSObjectType().newSObject(id);
            sob.put('Recent_Activity_Notes__c', t.Description);
            sob.put('Recent_Activity_Date__c, t.CreatedDate);
            sob.put('Recent_Activity_Owner__c, t.WhoId);
            sobs.add(sob);
        }
        update sobs;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect!   Is there a way to do this for contacts & leads.  I'm running into an error when trying to create based on WhoId

Comment: @AndrewSims See the PS. Not sure what owner you want for the contact/lead case though. You can alternatively use if/else logic based on the value returned by Id.getSObjectType() if that works better.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting the WHOID

```
Account acc = [SELECT Id, Recent_Activity_Notes__c, Recent_Activity_Date__c, Recent_Activity_Owner__c From Account WHERE Id = :t.WhoId ];
```

You need to be getting the AccountID

```
Account acc = [SELECT Id, Recent_Activity_Notes__c, Recent_Activity_Date__c, Recent_Activity_Owner__c From Account WHERE Id = :t.AccountId ];
```

Or more appropriate the WhatID

```
Account acc = [SELECT Id, Recent_Activity_Notes__c, Recent_Activity_Date__c, Recent_Activity_Owner__c From Account WHERE Id = :t.WhatId ];
```

Also, your comment

```
//We need to update associated Opportunity Fields with Fields from Case
```

Does not make sense as you are updating the account. Are you sure the code is doing what you want it to?